# SQL Insert Data If Column A Matches and Column B Doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, insert

I have a SQL Insert statement that needs to insert records into another table only if the the record doesn't exist in table2 or the zip code has changes in table1. I have tried the following but it throws an error and it is the logic I am looking for:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT id, zip
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id =  t2.id and t1.zip <> t2.zip
```

I also need it to insert the records if the id doesn't exist at all in table2. I have googled the crap out of this and can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

Comment: depending on your sql-server version `MERGE` might be a good starting point. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT t2.id, t2.zip
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE (t1.id IS NULL OR t2.zip <> t1.zip)
```

Also, be sure to clarify which table's `id` and `zip` columns you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should always include column lists when doing inserts.  Second, your query doesn't quite capture your logic.  You need a `left outer join` to find the records that don't exist in the second table.  Perhaps this might do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, zip)
SELECT id, zip
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE (t1.zip <> t2.zip) or (t2.zip is null)
```

Comment: Thanks I did t2.id is null instead and it works correctly. I was already adding the column names into the insert but didn't add them here for brevity

Answer (score -1):

You just need a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT id, zip
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.id AND table2.zip = table1.zip)
```